# What does the "-->" notation mean in the output of ifconfig?

Tags: networking, vpn, ifconfig

I have a VPN connection set up on my OS X machine, and when I run `ifconfig` in the terminal I get the following response:

```
utun0: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    inet 10.8.0.6 --> 10.8.0.5 netmask 0xffffffff
```

Can someone help me understand what the `-->` symbol means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the default gateway for that interface. TUN connections usually are p2p connections, which mean they are composed of a range with just 2 IPs, the gateway and the IP address.

You can verify that running `route -n` and seeing that the default gateway for your tun interface is indeed `10.8.0.5`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It looks like 10.8.0.5 is indeed my default gateway, though I had to use `netstat -rn` to view the routing table on OS X.